# Copy numpy array elements into multiple directions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So my broad problem is I have a large array of shape say (754, 580). First I wanted to fill this array with random numbers (from truncated normal distribution). This is pretty straightforward, `scipy.stats.truncnorm.rvs(..., size= (754, 580))` does the trick.

However, now I want to avoid having completely randomized numbers. Instead, I want each number to repeat `m` times in **both rows and columns** (and cut off at the edges). e.g., say I wanted to fill a (5,10) with m=3, the desired output could be like

```
[[0.32  0.32  0.32  0.569 0.569 0.569 0.532 0.532 0.532 0.75 ]
 [0.32  0.32  0.32  0.569 0.569 0.569 0.532 0.532 0.532 0.75 ]
 [0.32  0.32  0.32  0.569 0.569 0.569 0.532 0.532 0.532 0.75 ]
 [0.158 0.158 0.158 0.49  0.49  0.49  0.33  0.33  0.33  0.12 ]
 [0.158 0.158 0.158 0.49  0.49  0.49  0.33  0.33  0.33  0.12 ]]
```

since each element repeats three times along each row (except the last one, where it gets cut off because there are only 10, not 12, total columns), and repeats three times along each column (except the last one, which gets cut off because there are only 5, not 6, total rows).

I believe the cut-off is pretty easy to handle, I could just generate a (6, 12) array and then select only the first (5, 10) slice. But I'm having a hard time making the repeats happen in both x and y directions like in the example.

How can I do this for general `m`?

---

TLDR:

supplying m=3 for example how do I go from

```
[[0.32  0.569 0.532 0.75 ]
 [0.158 0.49  0.33  0.12 ]]
```

to (for set target size (5,10))

```
[[0.32  0.32  0.32  0.569 0.569 0.569 0.532 0.532 0.532 0.75 ]
 [0.32  0.32  0.32  0.569 0.569 0.569 0.532 0.532 0.532 0.75 ]
 [0.32  0.32  0.32  0.569 0.569 0.569 0.532 0.532 0.532 0.75 ]
 [0.158 0.158 0.158 0.49  0.49  0.49  0.33  0.33  0.33  0.12 ]
 [0.158 0.158 0.158 0.49  0.49  0.49  0.33  0.33  0.33  0.12 ]]
```

or even just

```
[[0.32  0.32  0.32  0.569 0.569 0.569 0.532 0.532 0.532 0.75  0.75  0.75 ]
 [0.32  0.32  0.32  0.569 0.569 0.569 0.532 0.532 0.532 0.75  0.75  0.75 ]
 [0.32  0.32  0.32  0.569 0.569 0.569 0.532 0.532 0.532 0.75  0.75  0.75 ]
 [0.158 0.158 0.158 0.49  0.49  0.49  0.33  0.33  0.33  0.12  0.12  0.12 ]
 [0.158 0.158 0.158 0.49  0.49  0.49  0.33  0.33  0.33  0.12  0.12  0.12 ]
 [0.158 0.158 0.158 0.49  0.49  0.49  0.33  0.33  0.33  0.12  0.12  0.12 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `np.kron` to create the tiles and then use slices to cut it to the desired size

```py
a = np.array([[0.32  0.569 0.532 0.75 ]
              [0.158 0.49  0.33  0.12 ]])
np.kron(a, np.ones((3, 3), dtype=a.dtype))[:5, :10]
```

```
[[0.32  0.32  0.32  0.569 0.569 0.569 0.532 0.532 0.532 0.75 ]
 [0.32  0.32  0.32  0.569 0.569 0.569 0.532 0.532 0.532 0.75 ]
 [0.32  0.32  0.32  0.569 0.569 0.569 0.532 0.532 0.532 0.75 ]
 [0.158 0.158 0.158 0.49  0.49  0.49  0.33  0.33  0.33  0.12 ]
 [0.158 0.158 0.158 0.49  0.49  0.49  0.33  0.33  0.33  0.12 ]]
```

Comment: what is `a` here?

Comment: `a` is your supplied array you want to repeat. See edited answer